# Check whether the statement true or false?

Tags: complex-analysis

Check whether the statement true or false?

Let $\mathbb D=\{ z\in \mathbb C||z|<1\}$ and $f:\mathbb D \to \mathbb C$ is an analytic function.For any closed curve $\gamma$ in unit disc $\mathbb D=\{ z\in \mathbb C||z|<1\}$, then $\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^2}dz=0,\forall z\in \mathbb C$ with $|a|\ge 1/2$.

If we consider the closed, $a=1/2$, $\gamma=\{z\in \mathbb C: |z-1/2|<1/8\}$, we get $2\pi i f'(1/2).$ Right? But in the answer key it is given that statement is true. please help me.

Comment: The question is not clear. It seems to miss some implications.

Comment: I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^2}dz=0,\forall z\in \mathbb C$ with $|a|\ge 1/2$ gives $2πif'(a)=0\ \forall |a|\ge 1/2$ which implies $f(a)=k\forall |a|\ge 1/2$. By Identity theorem $f(z)=k$ (a constant).